# numpy.array: TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

My program throws an error:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

I am using numpy and pandas with python 3.6. The error is encountered at line 15 identified with "**" below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")

print("Starting data manipulation...")
data = data[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]

predict = "G3"

x = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data([predict]))


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)

print("Accuracy: " + str(acc))

print("Coefficient: " + str(linear.coef_))
print("Intercept: " + str(linear.intercept_))
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

`y = np.array(data([predict]))`

to

`y = np.array(data[predict])`

When you use `()` after any variable, python expects it to be a function and that's what error message is about

Use only `[]` to access column from any dataframe i.e. `data["predict"]`